# $index inside ng-repeat with ng-if

Tags: angularjs

I Have an array of items like this which contains a list of animals and a list of fruits in a random order.

```
 $scope.items = [{name:'mango',type:'fruit'},{name:'cat',type:'animal'},{name:'dog',type:'animal'},{name:'monkey',type:'animal'},{name:'orange',type:'fruit'},{name:'banana',type:'fruit'},...]
```

Then I Have a array of colors like

```
$scope.colorSeries = ['#3366cc', '#dc3912', '#ff9900',...];

$scope.setBGColor = function (index) {
   return { background: $scope.colorSeries[index] }
}
```

I am using the items array to render the fruits only in a div with background color selected from the colorSeries based on the index like colorSeries[0] which will give me #3366cc

```
<div data-ng-repeat="item in items " ng-if="item.type =='fruit'">
   <label ng-style="setBGColor($index)">{{item.name}}</label>
</div>
```

Things working fine if the length of the items array is less than length of `colorSeries` array.The problem arises if the length of `colorSeries` array is less than the items array.e.g if i have a color series with 3 colors then for this items array the last item i.e orange will need a color indexed as `colorSeries[4]` which is `undefined` where as I have rendered only three items. So, is it possible to get the index like 0,1,2 i.e the index of elements rendered with `ng-if`.

Comment: so what do you want instead of colorSeries[4]? What logic are you trying to code to select the item from colorSeries?

Comment: instead i want colorSeries[2] since i have only three elements of type fruits.

Comment: please take your time to review the answers and choose a correct one (or add your solution, if different).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using *ng-if*, I would use a filter. then, the $index will be always correspond to the index in the result list after applying the filter

```
<div data-ng-repeat="item in items|filterFruit">
   <label ng-style="setBGColor($index)">{{item.name}}</label>
</div>

angular.module('app.filters', []).filter('filterFruit', [function () {
    return function (fruits) {
        var i;
        var tempfruits = [];
        var thefruit;

        if (angular.isDefined(fruits) && 
            fruits.length > 0) {
                for(thefruit = fruits[i=0]; i<fruits.length; thefruit=fruits[++i]) {
                   if(thefruit.type =='fruit') 
                      tempfruits.push(thefruit);
                }
        }
        return tempfruits;
    };
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
 this.itemList = [{
        name:'apple'
    }, {
        name: 'fruit'
    }];

    this.colorlist = [{ color: 'red' }, { color: 'orange' }, { color: 'blue' }];

  <div data-ng-repeat="item in itemList " ng-if="item.name=='fruit'">
  <label ng-style="colorlist [$index]">{{item.name}}</label>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would *embed* the colors inside the `$scope.items` objects, since you always use them coupled with a fruit.

Anyway, to address your specific code configuration, I would add a counter in my controller and use it to loop through the colors.
Something like this:

```
app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {

  $scope.colorSeries = ['#3366cc', '#dc3912', '#ff9900',...];

  var colorCounter = $scope.colorSeries.length;
  var colorIdx = -1;
  $scope.setBGColor = function () {
    // get back to the first color if you finished the loop
    colorIdx = colorCounter? 0: colorIdx+1

    return { background: $scope.colorSeries[colorIdx] }
  }

})
```

And then in your view (note that there is no `$index`)

```
<div data-ng-repeat="item in items " ng-if="item.type =='fruit'">
   <label ng-style="setBGColor()">{{item.name}}</label>
</div>
```